# adding System to linux bootings

Tags: windows, linux, bootloader

I've got linux installed on disc with BLoader but last time I added new disk on SATA which got windows on it. What should I do to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a chainload in your /boot/grub/menu.lst (or maybe /boot/grub/grub.conf):

```
title Windows
root (hd1,0) # the disk and partition your windows is installed on (starting at 0)
chainloader +1
```

The chainloader option tells grub to load the first sector of the root drive. In your case that would be the windows bootloader.